# JAVA - Robot mouse doesn't move the actual pointer

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm writing a piece of code to simulate the mouse movement. This code is run on NetBeans on a Linux KAD (it's a guest machine on Virtualbox, I don't know if is related to my issue)

```java
Robot bot = null;
try {
    bot = new Robot();
} catch (Exception failed) {
    System.err.println("Failed instantiating Robot: " + failed);
}
bot.mouseMove(1000, 500);
```

It's working properly, because if I add also a Click instruction I can see that is doing it in the right position, but the mouse pointer is not moving.
Is that an issue or is it like it is supposed to be? I would like also to see where the mouse is set by seeing the mouse pointer

Thanks

EDIT: I finally managed to test it outside the VM and it's working fine, so probably is a "limit" of the virtualization that prevent from actually move the pointer. Thanks to everybody

Comment: Is the Robot class something you were given?

Comment: @nicomp `java.awt.Robot` is the most likely option.

Comment: My guess here is that you are perfectly fine moving the VM's mouse, but you cannot see this mouse because of how the VM software forwards your actual mouse to the VM. You could add an overlay yourself to visualize where the mouse pointer is.

Comment: Note that the parameters to method [mouseMove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseMove-int-int-) are screen coordinates. Are you sure that you are moving the mouse to a location different to its current location **and** within the bounds of your application's window? For what it's worth, method `mouseMove` works fine for me. Maybe try posting a [mcve]?